# Using Linq to combine two lists and get total quantity

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two lists coming from two different warehouses.

```
var list1 = new List<Tshirt> {
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "blue", size="M", qty=3 },
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "red", size="M", qty=2 },
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "green", size="M", qty=3 },
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "blue", size="M", qty=3 },
}

var list2 = new List<Tshirt> {
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "blue", size="M", qty=5 },
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "red", size="M", qty=7 },
}
```

Using LINQ, how do I end up with a combined list like this.

```
var list3 = new List<Tshirt> {
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "blue", size="M", qty=11 },
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "red", size="M", qty=9 },
    new Tshirt(){ Color = "green", size="M", qty=3 }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is that correct that `list3` contains two `Tshirt` instances with `Color = "blue"` and `size = "M"` and `qty` of `8` and `3` instead of one instance where `qty = 11`?  If so, what are the conditions/logic that cause medium blue `Tshirt` instances of quantities `3`, `3`, and `5` in the input lists to be represented as `8` and `3` in the output list?  Also, what have you tried so far to implement this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to group all shirts by color and size then combine the qtys.

Comment: So far what I've tried was add list2 to list1 by using AddRange method. Then I create a list3 and loop over list1. If list3 already has the current color+size combination then I add the additional qty to it. Otherwise, I create a new item in list3 using the properties of current item. This seems highly inefficient though, I think LINQ is better suited for this sort of thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I originally answered this question incorrectly, see the second heading below ("To combine all distinct `Tshirt` instances together") for my original, irrelevant, answer)

### To combine all Tshirt instances and sum their qtys:

I see you're using a tuple of `color + size` to uniquely identify a type of t-shirt, which means if we combine all `Tshirt` instances together (`Concat`), then group them by `color + size`, then `Sum` the `qty` values, then return new `Tshirt` instances in a new list.

```
List<Tshirt> aggregatedShirts = uniqueShirts = Enumerable
    .Empty<Tshirt>()
    .Concat( list1 )
    .Concat( list2 )
    .GroupBy( shirt => new { shirt.Color, shirt.size } )
    .Select( grp => new Tshirt()
    {
        Color = grp.Key.Color,
        size  = grp.Key.size,
        qty   = grp.Sum( shirt => shirt.qty )
    } )
    .ToList();
```

### To combine all distinct `Tshirt` instances together

Assuming `class Tshirt` implements `IEquatable<Tshirt>` then just use `Concat( ... ).Distinct().ToList()`:

I'd do it this way, others might prefer not to use `Empty`:

```
List<Tshirt> uniqueShirts = Enumerable
    .Empty<Tshirt>()
    .Concat( list1 )
    .Concat( list2 )
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

If `Tshirt` does not implement `IEquatable` then you can use the overload of `Distinct` that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>`:

```
class TshirtComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tshirt>
{
    public static TshirtComparer Instance { get; } = new TshirtComparer();

    public Boolean Equals(Tshirt x, Tshirt y)
    {
        if( ( x == null ) != ( y == null ) ) return false;
        if( x == null ) return true;

        return x.Color == y.Color && x.size == y.size && x.qty == y.qty;
    }

    public Int32 GetHashCode(Tshirt value)
    {
        if( value == null ) return 0;
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode
        Int32 hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + value.Color?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        hash = hash * 23 + value.size?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        hash = hash * 23 + value.qty;
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Tshirt> uniqueShirts = Enumerable
    .Empty<Tshirt>()
    .Concat( list1 )
    .Concat( list2 )
    .Distinct( TshirtComparer.Instance )
    .ToList();
```

Then to get the total quantity:

```
Int32 totalQuantity = uniqueShirts.Sum( shirt => shirt.qty );
```

Comment: The input lists `list1` and `list2` have a total of three medium blue shirt instances, and the output list `list3` has two medium blue instances, with some quantities combined.  By using `Distinct()` won't this result in only one medium blue shirt instance?

Comment: @BACON Argh, you're right! I didn't read the question fully before answering.

Comment: @BACON I've updated my answer with a solution to the OP's actual question.

Comment: The new code still yields one `Tshirt` instance per combination of `Color`/`size`.  As I commented on the question itself, I don't know (or, at least, it's not explained) how code could know that medium blue shirts in quantities `3 + 3 + 8` should be combined to yield `8 + 3`.  Maybe no `Tshirt` instance can have `qty >= 10`?  Or there's something special about having two instances with `qty = 3` such that only one of them gets added to the `qty = 8` instance and the one remaining contributes to a new instance?  I think more information is needed.

Comment: @BACON Yes, the OP's question post is definitely low-effort - but I'm assuming my new answer is what they're looking for, because anything else doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, the code you provided makes more sense than what they (appear to be) asking for.  In fact, I'd be willing to bet that they created the code for `list3` by copying and pasting `list1` and forgot to delete the fourth `Tshirt` instance...

Comment: BACON, you are correct, my apologies for not double checking my question. I made the necessary correction.

Comment: Thank you Dai, that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
 var list3 = list1.Union(list2).GroupBy(o => new {o.Color, o.size})
                .Select(o => new Tshirt()
                {
                    Color = o.Key.Color,
                    size = o.Key.size,
                    qty = o.Sum(q => q.qty)
                }).OrderByDescending(o => o.qty).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, xiang wang, I like this terse solution too